# How do you set the cout locale to insert commas as thousands separators?

Tags: c++, formatting, numbers, number-formatting

Given the following code:

```
cout << 1000;
```

I would like the following output:

```
1,000
```

This can be done using std::locale, and the cout.imbue() function, but I fear I may be missing a step here.  Can you spot it?  I'm currently copying the current locale, and adding a thousands separator facet, but the comma never appears in my output.

```
template<typename T> class ThousandsSeparator : public numpunct<T> {
public:
    ThousandsSeparator(T Separator) : m_Separator(Separator) {}

protected:
    T do_thousands_sep() const  {
        return m_Separator;
    }

private:
    T m_Separator;
}

main() {
    cout.imbue(locale(cout.getloc(), new ThousandsSeparator<char>(',')));
    cout << 1000;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried compiling the exact code you want us to believe you are using?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a built-in function that comma-separates a number in C, C++, or JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3479485/is-there-a-built-in-function-that-comma-separates-a-number-in-c-c-or-javascri)

Comment: Is there a memleak?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The default implementation of `do_thousands_sep` already returns `','`. It looks like you should override `do_grouping` instead. `do_grouping` returns an empty string by default, which means no grouping. This means groups of three digits each:

```
string do_grouping() const
{
    return "\03";
}
```

Comment: What does the "\03" represent?  Is that ASCII for "end of text"?  If so, why?

Comment: @Cory: do_grouping returns a string that is treated as an array of one-char numbers that represent the size of the group. "\03" creates a string that has one and only one character with numeric value 3, which means that the groups will be of 3 digits each.

Comment: The default is not a ','. The C local uses no grouping, otherwise it is local specific.

Comment: @Martin: I'm talking about the default returned form do_thousands_sep which is ','. It's not the same as 'default locale'. "Returns: A character for use as the digit group separator. The required specializations return ’,’ or
L’,’."