# Segfault when imbueing stringstream with custom locale

Tags: c++, memory-management, locale, stringstream

Based on the answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7276826/c-format-number-with-commas) to the question of how to format numbers with a comma, I am using the following code:

```
#include <locale>
#include <stringstream>

namespace
{

class comma_numpunct : public std::numpunct<char>
{
  protected:
    virtual char do_thousands_sep() const
    {
        return ',';
    }

    virtual std::string do_grouping() const
    {
        return "\03";
    }
};

}


/* Convert number to string using a comma as the thousands separator. */
string thousands(const int x) {

    /* custom locale to ensure thousands separator is comma */
    comma_numpunct* comma_numpunct_ptr = new comma_numpunct();
    std::locale comma_locale(std::locale(), comma_numpunct_ptr);

    stringstream ss;
    ss.imbue(comma_locale); // apply locale to stringstream
    ss << x;

    /* garbage collection */
    delete comma_numpunct_ptr;

    return ss.str();
}
```

GDB gives the following backtrace:

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x0000000000000021 in ?? ()
(gdb) bt
#0  0x0000000000000021 in ?? ()
#1  0x00007ffff7701535 in std::locale::_Impl::~_Impl() () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6
#2  0x00007ffff770166d in std::locale::~locale() () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6
#3  0x000000000044b93e in thousands (x=358799) at ../globals_utilities.cpp:104
#4  0x000000000045650d in main (argc=1, argv=0x7fffffffdf58) at ../main.cpp:67
```

So, the problem is (I believe) with my attempt at freeing the `new`'d memory. But I don't know how to work around this.  (I can't use `std::unique_ptr` because I'm not always compiling with C++11 support.)

How can I fix the segfault without leaking memory?

Comment: You're not supposed to free the memory manually. The destructor of `std::locale` will do that for you.

Comment: why not just use a static object? No need to delete anything then.

Comment: @user4815162342 Still sigfaults.

Comment: You may find the Note on Option 7 for [`std::locale::locale()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/locale/locale) informative: "Overload 7 is typically called with its second argument, f, obtained directly from a new-expression: **the locale is responsible for calling the matching delete from its own destructor.**" In other words, don't delete what you no longer own.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is the locale facet (numpunct). If you pass it to a locale via constructor and the references of the facet is zero the locale will delete the facet.

You might do:

```
comma_numpunct(size_t refs = 0)
:   numpunct(refs)
{}
```

and

```
comma_numpunct* comma_numpunct_ptr = new comma_numpunct(1);
```

or better omit:

```
// double delete
// delete comma_numpunct_ptr;
```

You may omit the allocation of the facet:

```
string thousands(const int x) {
   comma_numpunct numpunct(1);
   std::locale comma_locale(std::locale(), &numpunct);
   std::stringstream ss;
   ss.imbue(comma_locale);
   ss << x;
   return ss.str();
}
```

From 22.3.1.1.2 Class locale::facet

> The refs argument to the constructor is used for lifetime management.
>
> — For refs == 0, the implementation performs delete
>   static_cast(f) (where f is a pointer to the facet)
>   when the last locale object containing the facet is destroyed; for
>   refs == 1, the implementation never destroys the facet.