# I need some help getting the right output stream format in decimal in C++17

Tags: c++17

I made this little currency converter program that convert dollar to franc, but when I put an amount of, for example $2000 and more, I do not have the correct format, I have this: `1.15165e+006`. 
I want the entire decimal amount.
Thanks

Convert USD to Franc CFA

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()

{

const double cfa_per_usd {575.825}; 

cout <<"**********Welcome to the USD to Franc CFA Converter************" << endl;

double cfa {0.0};

cout <<"\nEnter value in USD: ";
double dollar {0};
cin >> dollar;
cfa = dollar * cfa_per_usd;
cout << dollar <<" Dollar(s) is equivalent to " << cfa << " Francs CFA" <<endl; 

 return 0;
}
```

I found a partial answer to my problem, I have added the library , then added "fixed" key word and the "setprecision()":

cout << dollar <<" Dollar(s) is equivalent to " << fixed << setprecision(2) << cfa << " Francs CFA" <

But I realized that I only have zeros after the decimal point: just 2 “.00”, I changed the constant to 576.212 for a dollar, so if I convert $2000 I should have 1,1512,424.54 francs, but I just have 1152424.00 francs, the .54 is not there, any idea how to fix it?

Comment: Take a look on `manipulators` library, you should find something useful for your case.

Comment: Thanks. I looked at couple manipulators, tried them now the program is working. Pretty much the "<<fixed", fixed it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [c++: Format number with commas?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7276826/c-format-number-with-commas)

Answer (score 0):

I found a partial answer to my problem,  I have added the  library, then add "fixed" key word and the "setprecision()":

```
cout << dollar <<" Dollar(s) is equivalent to " << fixed << setprecision(3) << cfa << " Francs CFA" <<endl;
```

But I realized that I only have zeros after the decimal point: just 2 “.00”, I changed the constant to 576.212 for a dollar, so if I convert $2000 I should have 1,1512,424.54 francs, but I just have 1152424.00 francs, the .54 is not there, any idea how to fix it?