# How to format floating point numbers with decimal comma using the fmt library?

Tags: c++, fmt

I want to use the [fmt](https://fmt.dev/latest/index.html) library to format floating point numbers.

I try to format a floating point number with decimal separator ',' and tried this without success:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fmt/format.h>
#include <fmt/locale.h>

struct numpunct : std::numpunct<char> {
  protected:    
    char do_decimal_point() const override
    {
        return ',';
    }
};

int main(void) {
    std::locale loc;
    std::locale l(loc, new numpunct());
    std::cout << fmt::format(l, "{0:f}", 1.234567);
}
```

Output is `1.234567`. I would like `1,234567`

### Update:

I browsed the source of the fmt library and think that the decimal separator is [hard coded](https://github.com/fmtlib/fmt/blob/ab0ba8a9d0ef694bfb346cd3b2f238e5e270d826/include/fmt/format.h#L1089) for floating point numbers and does not respect the current locale.

I just opened an [issue in the fmt library](https://github.com/fmtlib/fmt/issues/1218)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [c++: Format number with commas?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7276826/c-format-number-with-commas)

Comment: @pandorafalters: I want to use the new fmt library. So I guess it is not a duplicate

Comment: @pandorafalters that's using `,` as a thousands separator, not as the decimal separator

Comment: Have you tried `std::locale("de_DE")` or similar?

Comment: @Caleth: std::locale("de_DE") does not work

Comment: Don't you have to imbue the output stream? E.g. https://wandbox.org/permlink/s4PdRDA8pYzbaDvl vs. https://wandbox.org/permlink/2LwYr8ZmuhwUYy26

Comment: @Bob__: Does not work since the formatting is not done by the ostream operator but the fmt library.

Comment: which OS and compiler? MSVC sucks when handling locale.

Comment: Also looks like this was fixed in `fmt` 5.3 see [release notes](https://github.com/fmtlib/fmt/releases/tag/5.3.0). Which version do you use?

Comment: @MarekR: No, fmt only respects the locale when using n for integers to chose which thousand separator should be used. (https://github.com/fmtlib/fmt/releases/tag/5.3.0) Improved Locale Support. I want to format a floating point number and this is done using the grisu algorithm. And there the decimal separator is hard coded. See above location.

Comment: Then file bug report.

Comment: @MarekR: Did it already: https://github.com/fmtlib/fmt/issues/1218

Comment: "does not respect the current locale" Global state is evil. They however should accept an optional locale argument.

Comment: @n.m.: As in my example code.

Comment: @schoetbi Consider making that an answer.

Comment: @n.m. some global state is less evil than others. Not all development occurs in the US

Comment: @Caleth I know, I am not in the US.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The fmt library made the decision that passing a locale as first argument is for overwriting the global locale for this call only. It is not applied to arguments with the `f` format specifier by design.

To format floating point number using locale settings the format specifier `L` has to be used, for example:

```
std::locale loc(std::locale(), new numpunct());
std::cout << fmt::format(loc, "{0:L}", 1.234567);
```

The `L` format specifier supports floating-point arguments as of revision [1d3e3d](https://github.com/fmtlib/fmt/commit/1d3e3d8c0466dedbb26547576e25a8f36f013520).

Comment: @Bob__: I updated the solution and added a link to [#1084](https://github.com/fmtlib/fmt/issues/1084).