# Printing numbers with Commas using <string> C++

Tags: c++, string, formatting

I'm really posting cause I've had this question in the past and found it slightly hard to find an answer. Eventually I did stumble upon something but it wasn't the cleanest thing. I've eventually progressed in my coding knowledge and I was able to make a function that seems pretty clean. Posting here to share and hopefully it helps others.

Comment: Looks like a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7276826/c-format-number-with-commas).

Comment: What do you mean by "printing numbers with commas"?

Comment: StackOverflow is a Q&A site.  While posting your own answers is OK and [even encouraged](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer), your post should be in the form of a question.

Answer (score 0):

EDITS: Several Edits due to issues dealing with negative numbers, solution is really a work around but still looks pretty neat by my standars.

I'm essentially relying on the to_string function and then just adding the commas where necessary.

```
inline string printWithCommas(unsigned int number) {
    string temp = to_string(number);
    unsigned int numLength = temp.size();

    temp.reserve((numLength - 1) / 3 + numLength);
    for (unsigned int i = 1; i <= (numLength - 1) / 3; i++)
        temp.insert(numLength - i * 3, 1, ',');
    
    return temp;
}
```

For integers that can possibly be negative.

```
inline string printWithCommas(int number) {
    if (number < 0)
        return string("-").append(printWithCommas((unsigned int)(number*-1));
    return printWithCommas((unsigned int)number);
}
```

For floating point and doubles it changes only for the initialization of numLength.

```
inline __device__ __host__ string printWithCommas(long double number) {
    if (number < 0)
        return string("-").append(printWithCommas(number * -1));

    string temp = to_string(number);
    unsigned int numLength = temp.find('.');

    temp.reserve((numLength - 1) / 3 + numLength);
    for (unsigned int i = 1; i <= (numLength - 1) / 3; i++)
        temp.insert(numLength - i * 3, 1, ',');

    return temp;
}
```

On my method file I have the function overloaded for every datatype to avoid mess with implicit conversions. So like:

```
inline std::string printWithCommas(int number);
inline std::string printWithCommas(long int number);
inline std::string printWithCommas(long long int number);

inline std::string printWithCommas(unsigned int number);
inline std::string printWithCommas(long unsigned int number);
inline std::string printWithCommas(long long unsigned int number);

inline std::string printWithCommas(float number);
inline std::string printWithCommas(double number);
inline std::string printWithCommas(long double number);
```

Comment: I've tested it a fair bit, if you find any issues it should just be on the position logic on the insert,. If I find anything I'll edit

Comment: `printWithCommas(-100)` looks a little suspect.

Comment: You can also specify a locale. Decent answer on doing that here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7277333/4581301

Comment: Yeah, forgot to test with negatives surprisingly enough, fml