# C++ format int numbers to separate thousands with a dot

Tags: c++, int, format

I'm working on Eclipse, on Fedora. I want to make a number more understandable using a dot to separate the thousands. This number is an integer Value that can be `0<Value<99.999`

So... if `Value = 1000` it shows `1000` and what I want is to show `1.000` (note the dot). The code I need to change is the next one:

```
char str[12];
sprintf(str, "%d", (int)(Value));
m_Text.SetText(str);
```

And what I thought is to do something like:

```
if (Value > 999) 
{
 int RightPart = (int)Value % 1000;
 int LeftPart = Val/1000 ;
}
```

And then append in a string  LeftPart + "." + RightPart so if `Value = 1563` it will be `1+.+563` which is `1.563`

My problem is that it's very ugly to do this and I was wondering if there were a better way of doing it. I've searched on google and found `imbue`and `locale`but they are only for cout. I've see too some posts like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4728155/how-do-you-set-the-cout-locale-to-insert-commas-as-thousands-separators) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7276826/c-format-number-with-commas) but this doesn't help me with my problem.

Thank you.

NOTE: I want to remark that I DON'T WANT to change the output format. I want to change the int I receive so I can have the dots in the str var with which I will work later.

NOTE 2: Basically the code has to: receive an integer (Value), and send it like a string to setText(). setText() will basically print it on the screen where and when it has to, and I want it to print 1.563 and not 1563 which is more  difficult to read.

Comment: You can use the C++ locale facilities to output numeric values with custom thousands-separators and decimal digits separators. See http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/numpunct for details. You can use stringstreams to format a string.

Comment: Use stringstream http://stackoverflow.com/a/7276879/786186

Comment: @AlessandroPezzato if I put `int Val = 1563; std::stringstream ss;
     ss.imbue(std::locale(""));
     ss << std::fixed << Val;
    sprintf(str, "%d", (int)(Val));
     std::cout << " ss = " << ss << " str = "<< str << std::endl;` then the output is `ss = 0xbfffe398 VAL = 5634 ` so I suppose that something has been wrong

Comment: @AlessandroPezzato I get the same now: `ss = 5634 str = 5634`

Comment: Because the question linked by @AlessandroPezzato has wrong answer accepted. Correct answer is by Node there.

Comment: @Megasa3 try `ss.imbue(std::locale("en_US.UTF-8"));`

Comment: @ÖöTiib O.o  you are right! Thank you! I put it and now it prints 1.000.000  if I write  `const int x = 1000000; std::cout << x << std::endl;` BUT If now I print str (which is the string I'm interested in, it prints 1563 still)

Comment: I just don't understand your last remark in the question. You first explain in a very detailed way how you want your number to be printed... only to then tell us that it's not about output but input?!

Comment: @ChristianHackl but i don't want it to be printed, I want it to be sent to setText in a special way that is with dots to separate thousands. I added a second note :) Sorry for the misunderstanding

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `stringstream` and same imbue technique for it.

For example:

```
struct dotted : std::numpunct<char> {
    char do_thousands_sep()   const { return '.'; }  // separate with dots
    std::string do_grouping() const { return "\3"; } // groups of 3 digits
    static void imbue(std::ostream &os) {
        os.imbue(std::locale(os.getloc(), new dotted));
    }
};
```

and then:

```
    std::stringstream ss;
    dotted::imbue(ss);
    ss << Value;
    std::cout << ss.str();
```

[<kbd>Demo</kbd>](http://ideone.com/zrPgHP)

Comment: With your cout I get the 1.563 Value I want BUT if I write `sprintf(str, "%d", (int)(Val)); std::cout << " str = "<< str << std::endl;`then it prints 1563. So I'm on the same way. As I said I don't want the visual output to change, I want the int received to change so I can hace the dots in the str.

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <iomanip>
#include <locale>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;

template<class T>
string format(T value)
{
    stringstream ss;
    ss.imbue(locale(""));
    ss << fixed << value;
    return ss.str();
}


int main(int argc, char argv[])
{
    cout.imbue(locale(""));
    cout << 1000000 << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Prints:

> 1.000.000

You should probably look at which locale is used when "" is passed and change it with a more appropriate one.

Or vice versa:

```
int str_to_nr(string str)
{
    int val;

    stringstream ss(str);
    ss.imbue(locale(""));
    ss >> val;

    return val;
}


int main(int argc, char argv[])
{
    cout << str_to_nr("1.000") << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Prints:

> 1000

Comment: Again, I don't want to change the output format, I want to change the int read format. I have added a note to my question to let it clear.

Comment: I'm still not sure if I completely understand what you'd like to achieve, but I updated my answer.

Comment: I have added a second note to clarify it more, sorry for the misunderstanding. I'll see later your answer cause now I can't test it

Answer (score 0):

[@gandgandi's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31656618/315052) basically gives you a technique to print out the value with dots on demand using C++ streams.

`sprintf` (which is generally not safe to use, BTW) is a C library function. C does not provide a mechanism to alter the locale behavior in the same way C++ provides. In C, you will have to define the locale behavior with mechanisms/tools provided by your operating system and assign it a name. Then, you can use the C function `setlocale` to alter the locale in the program to the one you have created to get it to print how you want. ***However***, this will only work on machines that have the locale you have created installed. It won't work on any other machine.

With only a little bit of work and almost no creative effort, you can just use the C++ solution already provided combined with a call to `sprintf`.

```
char str[12];
stringstream ss;
dotted::imbue(ss);
ss << Value;
sprintf(str, "%s", ss.str());
m_Text.SetText(str);
```

But, there is really no reason to use `sprintf` at all:

```
stringstream ss;
dotted::imbue(ss);
ss << Value;
m_Text.SetText(ss.str());
```